# $_GET variables empty .htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

`https://website.com/api/somefolder/test/512/31`

Should rewrite to:
`https://website.com/api/somefolder/test.php?param1=512&param2=31`

and

`https://website.com/api/somefolder/anotherfolder/hello/yo/44`

Should rewrite to:
`https://website.com/api/somefolder/anotherfolder/hello.php?param1=yo&param2=44`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The rewrite works but $1 and $2 are empty. Any idea why?

My htaccess file is located in the api directory.

Comment: I have a main htaccess in root. However, I wanted a separate htaccess for the sub directory api. So this htaccess is in the api folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule in `api/.htaccess` with `Options -MultiViews` at the top that turns off content negotiation service of Apache:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?param1=$2&param2=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error with your code as well when trying to access pages other than test.php. I want the re write rule to work for all PHP pages under api.

Comment: Unfortunately I get a 404 error with that code as well.

Comment: The only rewrite rule that doesn't give me a 404 is what I have in the question. Is there a way to use what I have but add on parameters? Forgive my ignorance when it comes to htaccess

Comment: With my code, I can navigate to test.php without the file extension (test). When I empty my htaccess file, I get a 404 when navigating to the same file without extension (test).

Comment: After putting random text in my htaccess, the page throws a 500 error.

Comment: Could the problem be that I am trying to access files that are multiple directories below the api folder (for example: https://api/folder1/folder2/folder3/filename/param1/param2)? Or maybe that the api folder is not in the www root (it is 1 directory below the www root)?

Comment: That works! I appreciate all of the help. There is one slight problem. When I do not pass in 1 or both arguments, it attempts to load the incorrect file. Is it possible to have optional parameters? Thanks again for all of the help!

Comment: https://website.com/CAT/api/translation/tasks/get/3/4x works correctly (get.php with 3 and 4x as parameters). https://website.com/CAT/api/translation/tasks/get/3 does not work (The requested URL /CAT/api.php was not found on this server).
------
For some reason, it tries to load api.php instead of get.php when only giving a single parameter.

Comment: Also, I changed RewriteBase to /CAT/

Comment: But your question is about handling 2 parameters only.

Comment: Should I go ahead and post a new question with the updated code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230378/how-do-i-make-parameters-optional-in-my-htaccess-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the two parameters are empty since you never full them with content...

Take a look at that example instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$
RewriteCond %1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %1.php?param1=%2&param2=%3 [QSA,END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I get a 404 not found error with the code you provided. I will continue testing to see if I can solve it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what the issue is. Could it have to do with the fact that I have a different htaccess file in my root and this htaccess is in the api directory?

Comment: That certainly will cause issues. It rarely is a good idea to spread configuration logic over several places.