# How do I make parameters optional in my htaccess rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want all of the following rewrites to be possible:

https://website.com/CAT/api/translation/tasks/get/3/4x

https://website.com/CAT/api/translation/tasks/get.php?param1=3&param2=4x

https://website.com/CAT/api/glossary/folder/anotherfolder/put/6

https://website.com/CAT/api/glossary/folder/anotherfolder/put.php?param1=6

The **first** url works fine. However, I want the amount of parameters to be optional. If I remove a parameter: https://website.com/CAT/api/translation/tasks/get/3/

I get the error **The requested URL /CAT/api.php was not found on this server.**


For some reason, only having 1 parameter causes the rewrite to change the folder api to api.php instead of the file get to get.php.

Here is my .htaccess which is located in the CAT directory.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CAT/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?param1=$2&param2=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: I guess challenge is to figure out which php file to load? So how to know from `https://website.com/CAT/api/glossary/folder/anotherfolder/put/6` whether php file is `/CAT/api/glossary/folder/anotherfolder/put.php` or `/CAT/api/glossary/folder/anotherfolder.php` ?

Comment: It seem so. It is confusing the file name depending on the amount of parameters.

Comment: So how to figure out php file name from long URL with variable no of parameters?